# Non-negativity of interaction information for special trivariate case

Tags: probability, statistics, information-theory, entropy

Consider a *discrete* trivariate distribution $P(X_1, X_2, Y)$, which satisfies
$$
p(x_1, x_2, y) = \min( p(x_1,y), p(x_2,y) ),
$$
for all $x_1$ and $x_2$ for which $p(x_1, x_2) > 0$ and for all values of $y$ (including those at which $p(x_1, x_2, y) = 0$). I am trying to show that then the interaction-information is non-negative
$$
I(X_1;Y) + I(X_2;Y) - I(X_1 X_2;Y) \ge 0
$$

I need either a rigorous proof or, alternatively, a counterexample that disproves the theorem.

**Addendum 1**: I use the shorthand notation $p(x_1, x_2, y) := P(X_1=x_1, X_2 = x_2, Y=y)$

**Addendum 2**: for a similar inequality and its proof see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.04867.pdf). This might provide some inspiration. For theoretical references on non-Shannon inequalities see [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/641561) and [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/681320).

**Addendum 3**: Note that the canonical example of negative interaction-information, the XOR gate, does not satisfy the theorem hypothesis. For the XOR gate $p(x_1, x_2, y) = \min \left( \ p(x_1,y), \ p(x_2,y) \ \right)$ holds for all $x_1, x_2, y$ such that $p(x_1, x_2, y)>0$ but not for all $y$ once we pick $x_1, x_2$ points for which $p(x_1, x_2)>0$, i.e. also the $y$s for which $p(x_1, x_2, y)=0$.

Comment: In your notation, does $p(x_1,y)$ denote the probability that $X_1=x_1$ and $Y=y$?

Comment: @pre-kidney: yes, I have now added this info to the question.

Comment: It looks like this is a non-Shannon inequality (see [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/641561) and [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/681320)). At the moment I am trying to understand whether the proof of Equation (3) from [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.04867.pdf) can be also applied to my problem. First I am to understand this proof in full...